# How to induce the Phonon Effective mode mass?

Tags: phonons, density-functional-theory

i don't know the phonon effective mode formula. Who knows why effective mode mass formula have the following form?

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.104.L060103 [PDF](https://journals.aps.org/prb/supplemental/10.1103/PhysRevB.104.L060103/QPE_SM.pdf)